# Using a value from a column as a value in an expression in LIKE statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, sql-like

I have a table `users` with registered users in the database of my website that has columns like `username` and `real_name`, emails, passwords, etc. I want to get all entries that contain their `username` in their `real name`.

Example:

```
id | username   | real_name
------------------------------
1  | JoshGrimes | JoshGrimesOG
2  | DanLurk    | Daniel Lurk
3  | AdamLevine | AdamLevineGJ
```

I need to select entries 1 and 3 as they contain their real name contains an exact match of their username.

Comment: `realname like concat('%',username,'%')` will work for that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `like`:

```
select t.*
from t
where real_name like concat('%', username, '%');
```

You can also use `locate()` or `position()`:

```
where locate(username, realname) > 0;
```